# JobDispatcher is not working in Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, firebase-job-dispatcher

I'm using a `JobDispacther` to fetch data from my server at night (around 1AM). I have tested on Jellybean, but when I test it on **Nougat 7.1.2(API 25)** , it does not work when the app is closed. I am using this code for testing purpose

```
class AutoFetch(context: Context){

    fun scheduleToFetchAtNight() {
      val job = jobDispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setService(AutoFetchService::class.java)
            .setTag("fetchAtNight")
            .setRecurring(false)
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(60, 60))
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK).build()
      val result = jobDispatcher.schedule(job)  
    }
}
```

**AutoFetchService**

```
class AutoFetchService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean {

        toast("Job Started")
        AutoFetch(this).scheduleToFetchAtNight()//Reschedule

        dataManager.fetchData{
            //on Fetched 
            jobFinished(job, false)
        }
    return true
    }
    override fun onStopJob(job: JobParameters): Boolean = true
}
```

I have also posted [Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/issues/181) at there site but still not getting any response,please Help